# How can I get the name of a PokéStop changed?

Tags: pokemon-go

There is a PokéStop located at my business, however it is listed under the business that was previously located here. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Probably by contacting Niantic, Inc support.

Comment: Report it as a bug. It's going to be low priority for them, though.

Answer (score 2):

They've currently disabled the feature to request new and modifications to portals/Pokestops which was available in the previous game (Ingress). The pokemon game uses the portal information from that game.

Most people suspect that they will re-enable this feature when things calm down and they're not as busy.

Answer (score 1):

You could login in ingress, in the portal view, there is a button to report an error with a portal, mostly for missplaced portals.

In Ingress, you can also upload another picture to suggest replacin the current one.

But we have no idea how the data will sync between the two games.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://uproxx.com/gammasquad/pokemon-go-get-rid-pokestops-gyms/) explains that the only known method to request the removal of PokéStops is this [form](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=319928) on Niantic's Pokemon GO site.

The [Google+ Pokémon GO - Pokestop & Gym Appeals](https://plus.google.com/communities/107845869620654469322) community mentioned in the post does not officially relate to Niantic. It was created due to the excessive and wrongly targeted Pokestop requests on the Ingress Portal Appeals community.